# DOM element's val() property when looping through class's array with jQuery

Tags: jquery

This works:

```
$('.validated').each(function(i, obj) {
    alert(obj.value);
});
```

I'm trying to use more jQuery to do the same thing, but these don't work:

```
$('.validated').each(function(i, obj) {
    alert('.validated'[i].val());
});
```

And

```
$('.validated').each(function(i, obj) {
    alert($('.validated')[i].val());
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Translate" is not a description of the problem you are trying to solve.  Please describe in words what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect. It should be :

```
$('.validated').each(function(i, obj) {
     alert($(this).val());
});
```

When working with jquery, you don't need to pass the `index`. `'this'` keyword would uniquely identify the single element in `each` function.

Comment: You either want `this.value` as @JoshCrozier pointed out, or `$(this).val()` or `$(obj).val()`. `this.val` will be undefined, though.

Comment: Updated  alert($(this).val());

Comment: @jmar777 you're right that `this.val` turned up undefined. could you please tell me why that was the case?

Comment: @user1883050: 'this' object doesn't contain a val property. But you can use this.id if needed

Comment: @user1883050 Within the .`each()` loop, `this` refers to the current DOM element on each iteration. When using a native DOM element, the correct way to retrieve the value is using `.value`, whereas `.val()` is actually a function defined by jQuery. That's why you have to "wrap" the element in jQuery (i.e., `$(this)` if you want to use `.val()`.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to translate it to jQuery.

Actually, the first example already was using jQuery. It appears what you're trying to do in the second snippet is something like this:

```
$('.validated').each(function(i, obj) {
    alert($('.validated').eq(i).val());
});
```

...which is worse than the previous example, as you end up running the selector again on each iteration.

If you're just wanting to be able to use `.val()` within the loop, you can do something like the following:

```
$('.validated').each(function(i, obj) {
    alert($(obj).val());
    // OR:
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. Gives me the option to not use `this` -- which I sometimes find confusing.

Comment: or just `alert(this.value);`